# Why are custom errors disabled for production environment deployment? Shouldn't it be the opposite?

Tags: asp.net, .net

The documentation for the [`<deployment>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228298%28VS.80%29.aspx) element in the web.config, in its **Remarks** section, says:

*"When retail is set to true, ASP.NET disables certain configuration settings such as trace output, custom errors, and debug capabilities."*

Why would ASP.NET turn off custom errors for a production environment? Wouldn't you want custom errors *enabled* esp. for the production environment?

When I am debugging locally, I like to see the yellow screen of death with the entire stack trace, but I wouldn't want that to show to my customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're [looking at the .NET 2.0 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228298(v=vs.80).aspx).

From [.NET 3.5 on](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228298(v=vs.90).aspx), it is:

> When the retail attribute is true, ASP.NET disables trace output, disables debug capabilities, and disables detailed system-generated error messages for remote users. For applications that have a customErrors element in the application Web.config file, the mode attribute is forced to On. These settings override any settings that are made in application Web.config files.

As [@Alexei indicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28747855/why-are-custom-errors-disabled-for-production-environment-deployment-shouldnt#comment45778376_28748090), the text for 2.0 was wrong too:

> The documentation is incorrect with regard to custom errors. The retail setting disables detailed 
>   system-generated error messages displayed to remote users, and for 
>   applications that have a customErrors element in their application 
>   web.config file, it overrides the mode attribute to set it to "On".

Comment: Thank you. Looks like they fixed a bug.

Comment: There is also comment below the article for 2.0 that "disables ... custom errors" statement is incorrect...

Comment: Thank you. It turns out that the page I was reading the documentation for prior to this page also had a lot of errors. It was the page on the `HandleErrorAttribute` exception filter in MVC. That one has plenty of errors.